# how to get session object from resource resolver factory?

Tags: java, aem, sightly, htl

```
@Component
public class AddNode {
    @Reference
    static ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;
    static Session session;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 


        ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(null);

        session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);        
          Node root = session.getRootNode(); 

          Node adobe = root.addNode("ProgramNode"); 
          Node day = adobe.addNode("subnode"); 
          day.setProperty("jcr:title", "programNode"); 

          Node node = root.getNode("ProgramNode/subnode"); 
          System.out.println(node.getPath()); 
          System.out.println(node.getProperty("jcr:title").getString()); 
          session.save(); 
          session.logout();


        }

}
```

here  resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(null);  i need to  pass any parameter at null.please give some example to get access of repository.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to create a page, an asset etc.? Because you are using more or less the lowest possible API to create content in JCR. Usually, you would not use the JCR API to do this but the Sling or if possible the AEM APIs.

Comment: i am new to AEM. trying to create node programatically throung java code not in crxde.

Answer (score 1):

We should use [System Users](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/security-service-users.html) to access repository when accessing via Factory. You would need to

1. Create system user, provide appropriate permissions
2. Map bundle symbolic name to system user
3. Use system user to get session via `ResourceResolverFactory`

   ```
   Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "<sub-service-name>");
   ResourceResolver resolver = null;         
   resolver = resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);
   session = resolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
   ```

You can refer [this helpx](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/jqom.html) link article also to get idea about using Service Users to create session

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of ResourceResolverFactory.

https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolverFactory.html